# Identifying when exponential function argument has doubled or tripled

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function

Suppose that I have a function $f(k) = U\exp(k)$.  Suppose also that I know $f(k)$, but not $k$ or $U$.
I modify this function as shown below, and take $k= k_0$ and $U$ as fixed constants:

$f(k=k_0,x) = U\exp(k)\exp(x) =  U\exp(k + x)$

I evaluate $f(k,x)$ for a number of $x$, so that $f(k=k_0,x)$ is a curve that I can graphically represent.  Note that $k+x$ is nothing more than the equation of a line, with $k$ as the y-intercept.

Knowing only $x$, and not knowing $k = k_0$ and $U$, can I identify $f(k,x)$ where the exponential function has doubled or tripled?  Why or why not?

Would there be some sort of numerical method (or something simpler) to do this?  What about using derivatives?  I want to be able to identify function values $f(k_0,x=k)$ and $f(k_0,x=2k)$ such that:

$f(k_0,x=k) =  U\exp(2k)$

$f(k_0,x=2k) =  U\exp(3k)$

**EXAMPLES**

Here's some examples to provide context for my question.  Initially, take $U = 1$ as a constant, and take $f_1$ as:

$f_1 = U\exp(3) = \exp(3)$

$\log(f_1) = 3$

Now suppose that the exponential function argument doubles, so that:

$f_2 = \exp(2\times3) = \exp(6)$

$\log(f_2) = 6 = 2\log(f_1)$

So if the exponential argument function doubles or triples, and $U = 1$, and I know $\log(f_1)$, it is possible to compute the following:

$\log(f_1) = 3$

$\log(f_2) = 2\log(f_1) = 6$        ........if the argument doubles

$\log(f_3) = 3\log(f_1) = 9$        ........if the argument triples

**When $U = 1$, I can predict $\log(f_2)$ and $\log(f_3)$ only by knowing $\log(f_1)$.**  But if $U \neq 1$, and I don't know $U$, it becomes trickier.  For example, take $U = 2 $ so that:

$g_1 = 2\exp(3)$

Then:

$\log(g_1) = \log(2) + 3$

$\log(g_2) = \log(2) + 6$ ........if the argument doubles

$\log(g_3) = \log(2) + 9$ ........if the argument triples

**So here is the gist of my question: Is there any way to determine $\log(g_2)$ and $\log(g_3)$ by only knowing $\log(g_1)$ and without knowing anything else?  Suppose that I don't know the RHS of the equations above, and note that on the RHS the $\log(2)$ term shows up in each of the equations.**

Note also that:

$\log(g_1) = \log(2) + 3$

$\log(g_2) \neq 2\log(g_1) = \log(2^2) + 6 \neq \log(2) + 6$

$\log(g_3) \neq  3\log(g_1) = \log(2^3) + 9 \neq \log(2) + 9$

Now say that I take $x = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...$ and compute:

$g(x) = 2\exp(3)\exp(x) = 2\exp(3+x) $

From the curve of $g(x)$, can I find when $g(x=3)$ or $g(x=6)$, when the argument has doubled or tripled?

Can I use curve-fitting to identify when the argument has doubled or tripled?  **Perhaps one way to do this would be to compare two curves and use some sort of optimization algorithm to minimize the sum of squared errors?**

Comment: I don't quite understand "identifying points on the curve where the exponential function has doubled or tripled". I think your $f(k = k_0, x) = U \exp(k) \exp(x)$ is just a constant multiple of $\exp(x)$, and the constant is arbitrary. I don't believe you can gain any more information other than what you are given.

Comment: Thanks, Tunococ; I've updated the question above and added more information in an attempt to show what I am trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in your first line.  $U\exp (k)$ is a constant and nothing you are doing can tease apart $U$ and $k$.  In fact, it equals $\exp (k + \ln U)$.  You can multiply it by $\exp (x)$ all you want and can't tell it from $\exp((k-\ln 2)+ \ln (2U))$ (for example).

Comment: I totally agree. There is NOTHING you can do to split $U$ and $\exp(k)$ apart.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks Ross.  Is there anything that can be done to estimate $U$ or $k$, given some additional information (bounds on $U$ or $k$), or some change in $U$ or $k$?

Comment: I am reminded again of a curve-fitting problem example: http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1500/1508.html.  The $A$ and $\lambda$ parameters are being found from $f = A\exp(\lambda t)$, where $A$ and $\lambda$ are constants, and $t$ is a variable.  Why does the curve-fitting problem work, and what makes the curve-fitting solution unique, unlike the problem that I posted above?

Comment: I agree as well that there is nothing that can be done to exactly split $U$ and $\exp(k)$ apart, but maybe there is a way to estimate $U$ or $k$.

Comment: @NicholasKinar:  for the curve fit example, you are able to change the exponent.  The $t$ multiplies $\lambda$, so you can tell the two variables apart.  Here you don't have that.  It's like trying to solve $x+y=2$ with no further information except that you can add $z$ and find $x+y+z=5$ when $z=3$.  You still have one equation with two unknowns.

Comment: @Ross: Thanks for pushing me in the right direction, Ross. I really appreciate your help and the help of other members of this site.